# I am doing codewars challenge Replace With Alphabet Position, but i don't understand it

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

The  challenge says given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.

For 4 hours i couldn't find a solution. I tried regex(don't really understand how does it works yet). And i tried to find a solution, but i don't understand it fully

The code is this

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
var code = text.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i)
if (code > 64 && code < 91) {
result += (code - 64) + " "
};
}

return result.slice(0, result.length-1);
}
```

I don't understand after var code = ......
Why doing this

```
if (code > 64 && code < 91) {
result += (code - 64) + " "
};
```

Comment: `code` refers to the ASCII character code of the uppercase letter, in which A = 65 and Z = 90. By subtracting 64 from `code` you end up with the (`1`-based) position in the alphabet (`a = 65`, `65 - 64 = 1`). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
```

This simply loops over every letter in the text parameter.

```
var code = text.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i)
```

This begins to define the letter's alphabet position. It basically says: "for every character in `text`, return its character code `charCodeAt(i)`.

```
if (code > 64 && code < 91) {
result += (code - 64) + " "
};
```

Just what the first comment says, the character codes for uppercase letters A thru Z start at 65 (A) and end at 90 (Z). Therefore, we only want the codes for letters A thru Z (e.g., we don't care about codes for spaces or quotation marks).
Since we want A to equal 1, we must subtract 64 from the character code 
(65 - 64 = 1, likewise for B, 66 - 64 = 2, etc).

```
result += (code - 64) + " "
```

This portion adds our filtered letter codes to the result and adds a space for readability. It does it for every character code filtered by the `if` statement.

```
return result.slice(0, result.length-1);
```

Then, we simply return the entire string and subtract the unnecessary space at the end.

Note: you could also simply return `result.trim()` to remove the whitespace at the end.